# VSCodeVim - binding copy/replace word under cursor

Tags: editor, visual-studio-code, vim-plugin, vscodevim

I need to copy the word under cursor, navigate to a different word in the document and replace it with the previous one I copied.

I do this so often that I use some custom key bindings for this.

<kbd>f</kbd> maps to <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> (**Y**ank **I**n **W**ord)

<kbd>f</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> maps to <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> (Select **I**n **W**ord with **V**isual mode and **P**aste)

So I can just <kbd>f</kbd> to copy, navigate and <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> to replace the word.

How can I specify this custom remapping on VSCodeVim ?

I tried pasting the following into `settings.json`, (and a few other using commands with the `editor.` prefix) but I can't get it to work.

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
    {
        "before": ["f"],
        "after": ["y", "i", "w"]
    },
    {
        "before": ["f", "f"],
        "after": ["v", "i", "w", "p"]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

try assign another hot key instead of ["f", "f"], I use ["<leader>", "s"] and it works well.
I guess two consecutive f key is confusing vscode with the f key in your copy tuple

Comment: Thanks for your answer Royce. I works indeed. However, I would be nice if I could just map it to "ff", as I find this easier personally and I use it with plain vim all the time. I ended up using a different (single) key instead ("f" -> "yiw" and "n" maps to "viwp"). I will up-vote your answer, however.